# wordpress gallery: Is there a way/pluggin allowing two or more native galleries in one page?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, nextgen-gallery

We are creating a *wordpress-based* project, but we came to an issue where we need to add two or more native wordpress galleries (to keep the *fancybox* plugin viewing). So is there a plugin/way **how to add more native galleries into one wordpress page?**

PS: We tried *nextgen*, but then the large view opens 2 times 1time *fancybox* 1time *nextgen gallery* ... So theoreticly it would be enaugh to turn off the *nextgen* viewing, but keep the *nextgen gallery* generation but the question is how?

PS2: We found a half-solution - you can add two [shortcodes] with image ids like
http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode but this way you can click through to all these galleries - but our goal is two click through only in each gallery itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it IS coding, but just a little ;-) :

1. make a specific CSS class e.g. .mySuperGallery01
2. into your page, insert a gallery shortcode e.g.

   ```
   [gallery link="file" size="medium" ids="332,330,331"]
   ```

   that list of ids are ids of images uploaded through the media...
3. wrap the gallery shortcode with your e.g. div class like this:

   <div class="mySuperGallery01">[gallery link="file" size="medium" ids="332,330,331"]</div>
4. For every shortcoded gallery wordpress will create an id #gallery-X where X is the order-number of your gallery on your page (#gallery-1, #gallery-2, #gallery-3,...)
5. Now go to settings =>  **Fancybox for WP => Extra Calls**
6. check that the "Additional FancyBox Calls" option is checked (turned-on)
7. Link through jquery to the galleries and add a groupNUMBER to each link but a different one for every next gallery by putting this into the textarea:

   ```
   $('.smallerGallery01 #gallery-X a').attr('rel','groupNUMBER');
   ```

   one gallery = one piece of this code... just change the X and a NUMBER to the same value for every gallery example:

   ```
   $('.smallerGallery01 #gallery-1 a').attr('rel','group1');
   $('.smallerGallery02 #gallery-2 a').attr('rel','group2');
   ```
8. Last thing you need to do is to actually "play" the fancybox on your class by inserting e.g. this code to the textarea:

```
jQuery(".smallerGallery01 a").fancybox({
    'cyclic': false,
    'autoScale': true,
    'padding': 10,
    'opacity': true,
    'speedIn': 500,
    'speedOut': 500,
    'changeSpeed': 300,
    'overlayShow': true,
    'overlayOpacity': "0.3",
    'overlayColor': "#666666",
    'titleShow': true,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'enableEscapeButton': true,
    'showCloseButton': true,
    'showNavArrows': true,
    'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'width': 560,
    'height': 340,
    'transitionIn': "fade",
    'transitionOut': "fade",
    'centerOnScroll': true

});
```

9)Dummy entry: Of course you have to click the save changes button ;-)

**NOTE:** I recommend you to go step by step especially through the jQuery settings

*ADVANTAGE:* Since you have a specific class, you can also make specific styles just for your new-style gallery :)